# How to efficiently access a firestore reference field's data in flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Using similar code as [flutter's firestore example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/example/lib/main.dart), suppose there is a reference field stored in a snapshot document, called: `document['userRef']`.

First of all, how do I access the data of userRef? Using `document['userRef'].get().data` or `document['userRef'].get().username` I wasn't able to access the data. (`NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<DocumentSnapshot>' has no instance getter 'data'`)

I also tried using `document['userRef'].get().then(...)` but getting the error: `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Even if `.then` would work, wouldn't it then look up the same reference again for each message? Here the database is updated in realtime, but it's unnecessary to make the same lookup for multiple messages in the ListView.

```
class MessageList extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageList({this.firestore});

  final Firestore firestore;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
        final int messageCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: messageCount,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
            final DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];
            // document['userRef'] exists here
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(document['message'] ?? '<No message retrieved>'),
              subtitle: Text('Message ${index + 1} of $messageCount'),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:
I was able to fetch the nested data using FutureBuilder, though not sure how efficient it is. (Wouldn't this possibly send loads of redundant requests to Firebase?)

Creating a widget for the nested data, where document['userRef'] exists:

```
        FutureBuilder(
          future: userData(document['userRef']),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> uData) {
            return Text(uData.data['username']);
          },
        );
```

And the userData function looks like this:

```
Future<dynamic> userData(DocumentReference user) async {
  DocumentSnapshot userRef = await user.get();
  return userRef.data;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sticking to the Firebase and Flutter way, it is possible to use a Streambuilder inside a Streambuilder. That is, instead of using a FutureBuilder for the nested data, which makes you wait for each .get request.

(The code is untested, but the principle is tested.)

```
class MessageList extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageList({this.firestore});

  final Firestore firestore;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map UserSnapshot = Map(); // create a variable for accessing users by id

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: firestore.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> UsersSnapshot) {
          // process usersnapshot from list to map
          UsersSnapshot.data.documents.forEach((userRecord) {
            //print(optionRecord.documentID); // debug
            UserSnapshot[userRecord.documentID] = userRecord;
          });
          // user data can be accessed as soon as there is a reference field or documentID:
          // UserSnapshot[document['userRef']]['userName'}

          return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> MessagesSnapshot) {
              if (!MessagesSnapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
              final int messageCount = MessagesSnapshot.data.documents.length;
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: messageCount,
                itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                  final DocumentSnapshot document =
                      MessagesSnapshot.data.documents[index];
                  // document['userRef'] exists here
                  // UserSnapshot[document['userRef']]['userName'} is accessible here
                  return ListTile(
                    title:
                        Text(document['message'] ?? '<No message retrieved>'),
                    subtitle: Text('Message ${index + 1} of $messageCount'),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: it was headache to get the code working but did it - thx. Naming the variables with first letter upper case is best way how to make your code unreadable tho. For those who missed it (I did), there are 2 different variables UserSnapshot and UsersSnapshot, so beware. And at the end you have to use document['userRef'].documentID not just the reference.